# jquery/javascript show or delay effect

Tags: delay, show

I'm looking to make an image sprite fade in after a certain amount of time. (please see code below)

The image sprite has CSS attributes such as hover, active, href.
Then I added jquery src and code. The sprite hover, active, href work, but the jquery delay does not.

How do I make all of these work together?

Thanks for any help you can give!

K

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">

<style type="text/css">
html, body {margin:0px;}

a.LaunchCourse {
background: url(images/LaunchCourse.png) no-repeat 0 0;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 188px;
height: 60px;
}

a.LaunchCourse:hover{
background-position: 0px -60px;
}

a.LaunchCourse:active{
background-position: 0px -120px;
}

</style>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.LaunchCourse').delay(1500).fadeIn(1500);
});
</script>


</head>

<body>

<a class="LaunchCourse" href="wbt.htm" ></a> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you might want to try is putting this:

```
$('.LaunchCourse').hide();
setTimeout(showImage, 5000);

function showImage() {
    $('.LaunchCourse').fadeIn(1000);
}
```

instead of this:

```
$('.LaunchCourse').delay(1500).fadeIn(1500);
```

That way, you start by hiding the image... and then you just fade in with however much delay you want in that fadeIn(***number***) part.

Comment: Hi Summea,

Thanks for your answer...It's partially working. :)
With the code you suggested the image does fade in over a 1.5 sec period, but what I would ALSO like is for the image to NOT be present on the screen at all for about 63000 (a little over a min).

I tried adding 5000 to the hide(); attr., but it then does just that in the corner of my screen; it took the image and 'hid' it over a 5 sec period.

What do I need to add to keep the image hidden before it fadesin?

Comment: Have you tried adding that **63000** value in place of the **1500** value in the example?  I think you'll want to leave the hide() function as it is (with no parameters,) for now. :)

Comment: I did...and when I tried that it sloooooooowwwwwwwwwly fades the image in over the period of a min. You can start to see the image after about 15 sec, 50% opacity at 30 sec...etc.
What I want to do is have the image completely hidden for over a minute, not slowly fading in for over a minute. :)

Comment: Gotcha; alright, I updated the answer to reflect what you are wanting it to do (I think.) :) You can change that 5000 value to whatever you need in that setTimeout() function. How does it look?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript's setTimeout function?

Comment: Sounds great, but I'm not sure what that would look like...I'm sorry, but I'm very new to jquery/javascript.

Comment: I've looked at w3schools, but all of their examples seem to involve a click in order for the event to happen...I don't want click to be involved; I just want the image/link to fade in after a certain amount of time. Again, I'm not adept enough to manipulate their code to take out the click handler so the event starts on its own. :)

Comment: I can write the code for you.  What event (page load, DocReady, etc) do you want to start the timer?